# How to switch channel when source disconnected

Tags: jquery, jplayer

```
var myPlayer = $("#jquery_jplayer_1"),
    channelIndex = 0,
    channels = [
        'http://www.example1.com/fm.mp3',
        'http://www.example2.com/fm.mp3'
    ],
    options = {
        ready: function (event) {
            $(this).jPlayer("setMedia", {
                mp3: channels[channelIndex]
            });
        },
        error: function(event) {
            if (channelIndex === 0) {
                channelIndex = 1;
            } else {
                channelIndex = 0;
            }

            $(this).jPlayer("setMedia", {
                mp3: channels[channelIndex]
            }).jPlayer('play');
        },
        pause: function() {
            $(this).jPlayer('clearMedia');
        },
        swfPath: "assets",
        supplied: "mp3",
        cssSelectorAncestor: "#jp_container_1",
        wmode: "window",
        keyEnabled: true
};

myPlayer.jPlayer(options);
```

I setup two stream source, and HTML5 player to play it on web page, I use [jPlayer](http://jplayer.org/) to do that, the second channel is ready for prevent if the first one is disconnected, but I can't find the disconnect event on jPlayer, I set it in `error` event, if the first channel disconnect at beginning, it will switch to second channel, but if disconnect when playing, the player just stop like the source is finished, how to check if the channel is disconnected during playing.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried below events

$.jPlayer.event.emptied

$.jPlayer.event.ended

you can use both to find if media is ended or suspended. described here http://jplayer.org/latest/developer-guide/#jPlayer-event-type

Comment: Yup I tried, I console something under those two events, but when I offline the first channel when playing they don't show anything

Comment: Excuse me, `ended` seems work, although I think is not the best solution, but thanks

Comment: You can use combination of these events


    $.jPlayer.event.stalled **


    $.jPlayer.event.waiting  **


    $.jPlayer.event.canplay 

    $.jPlayer.event.canplaythrough

Comment: How to get canplay event in ready? I tried `console.log($.jPlayer.event.canplay)` in `ready: function() {` only get string `jPlayer_canplay`

Comment: stalled happened all the time, I can't use it for check connection

Comment: I can't find any better solution, I just use ajax and php to solve the problem